# Using VLookup Function on a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames **l3** which contains 559 rows and the other day frame **'mains'** contains 58 rows and now I want to create a column 'new' in l3 such that if the value in l3 column 'dum' is present in any of the rows of the column 'Datecomb' in mains dataframe then the new column should contain True else False

I Tried :

```
def f(i):
    if((i == (mains['Datecomb']).any()) == True):
        return 'True'
    else:
        return 'False'

 l3['new']=l3['dum'].apply(f)
```

But this function returned only "False"
I used value counts for both l3['dum'] and mnains['Datecomb'] and i could see common values using Ctrl+F option on chrome...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific request, we can actually do this in one line with some method chaining and list comprehension:

```
I3['new'] = [mains['Datecomb'].where(mains['Datecomb'] == i).count() > 0 for i in I3['dum'].values]
```

This expression uses list comprehension to count the number of entries in **mains['Datecomb']** for each value in **I3['dum']**, returns **True** if that count is > 0, and sets the resulting list as a column **I3['new']**.

If you are unfamiliar with list comprehension, take a look online as some examples. It is a powerful tool!

Alternatively, you can use the **DataFrame.join()** method to join the results of a **value_counts() > 0** operation on **mains**:

```
I3 = I3.join(mains['Datecomb'].value_counts() > 0, on = 'dum').fillna(False)
I3 = I3.rename(columns={'Datecomb': 'new'})
```

For more general lookup operations, using the join(), merge(), or concat() methods are probably better. I just found the first method above to work well for your specific request

I tested this on the following sample data set and both methods worked

```
I3 = pd.DataFrame([
     ['dum1', 'old1'],
     ['dum2', 'old2'],
     ['dum3', 'old3'],
     ['dum4', 'old4']],
     columns = ['dum', 'old'] )
mains = pd.DataFrame([
     ['dum2', 'not_used2'],
     ['dum3', 'not_used3'],
     ['dum3', 'not_used4']],
     columns = ['Datecomb', 'NotUsed'])
```